# How do I increment a date by 1 day in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If I have a `textbox1` and `button1`, where in textbox1 the date will display as `01-Apr-2011`, I want to click on `button` and have the date in `textbox1` increase by 1 day.

So, if `textbox1`s date is `01-Apr-2011` then in `textbox1` after clicking the button, `textbox1`s date will be `02-Apr-2011`, a further click will get `03-Apr-2011` and so on.

How do I do this using VB.NET?

Answer (score 16):

First you use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) to get the corresponding date-time instance and then use [DateTime.AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) to add the day and then format the date-time object to string again.
For example,

```
Dim currentDate as DateTime
currentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(textbox1.Text, "dd-MMM-yyyy", null);
currentDate.AddDays(1)
textBox1.Text = currentDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the control *is* called `textbox1` your click handler needs to do something like this:

```
Dim currentDate as DateTime
' Get the current date from the textbox
currentDate = Convert.ToDate(textbox1.Text)
' Add one day
currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1)
' Write the date back to the textbox
textBox1.Text = currentDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Note: The exact format of the date written back to `textbox1` may not match precisely what you're after - you'll almost certainly want to use [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) and choose an appropriate [format pattern](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).

Comment: this will not display date as 01-Apr-2011

Comment: @sumit - I've changed the answer to show the format string you're after. The details of how to generate that format string are detailed in the "Note" section of my answer

Comment: Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim currentDate As DateTime
        ' Get the current date from the textbox
        currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text)
        ' Add one day
        currentDate.AddDays(1)
        ' Write the date back to the textbox
        TextBox1.Text = currentDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
    End Sub

Comment: Not works if i set the default date in textbox1 as 01-Apr-2011

Comment: @sumit - ahh, I realised my mistake, I forgot (again!) that `DateTime.AddDays` returns a new `DateTime`, rather than adding a day to the existing `DateTime` - see the change to the third line of code, it now reads `currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1)` =)

Answer (score 1):

Something extra that I just had to use and is quite obvious, but to minus 1 day from a date in VB.NET you would do the following:

```
myDate = Mydate.AddDays(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

different ways to add one day to a datetime object

```
 Dim dt as DateTime(2011,10,12)
    dt = dt.AddDays(1)
    dt = dt.AddHours(24)
    dt = dt.AddMinutes(1440)
    dt = dt.AddSeconds(86400)
```

result will be 16 that is 12 + 4 days